# Torque on a rotating block vs torque on anchor bolt at its base

Tags: torque

[image]

If I apply a force perpendicular to the side of a 2D block at $\tfrac{H}{2}$ its height with a fixed bottom corner opposite the applied force, and an anchor bolt is placed $\tfrac{W}{2}$ from the pivot.  How much force will be applied to the anchor bolt relative to the initial applied force?

- Block Mass : M
- Block Width : W
- Block Height : H
- Applied Force : F
- Distance between force and pivot : r

I think the torque relative to the pivot will be:
$$
F \cdot r \cdot \sin( ∠A ) $$

I"m unsure how much of that torque is applied to the anchor bolt.  Would it be 50% of the torque at the pivot since it is in the bottom *middle* of the block?

Comment: Is the anchor bolt in the middle ($\tfrac{W}{2}$ distance from pivot?)

Comment: Yes, it's  $ \tfrac{W}{2} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a free body diagram ( I included the weight $W=mg$)

[image: fbd]

Then balance the forces and moments about the pivot

$$\begin{align} 
  -F +A_x & = 0 & \mbox{x-axis} \\
  -m g -A_y + B_y & = 0 & \mbox{y-axis} \\
   \frac{W}{2} (B_y-m g) + \frac{H}{2} F & = 0 & \mbox{torque}
\end{align} $$

to be solved for $A_x$, $A_y$ and bold froce $B_y$.

Comment: Yes. The _arbitray_ convention I used would result in negative bolt force. Any negative result needs the sense of the force flipped from the diagram.

Comment: @sammygerbil - AHA, now I see. I will correct the equations. Thank you for checking my work. The moment of $F$ is positive (CCW from pivot).